# How do I respond to an error in a promise when sending an SMS through Twilio?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, twilio

I've built a small nodejs api that takes a phone number as input, sends the user a verification text through Twilio, and then creates a new user. I'm calling Twilio to send the text message in the function below:

```
module.exports = function (recipient, message) {

    client.messages
        .create({
            body: message,
            from: '+16468464111',
            to: recipient
        })
        .then(message => {
            winston.info('Sent invite to ' + recipient + ' with SID ' + message.sid);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            winston.error(error);
        });

}
```

And then I'm calling that function from my Express route like this:

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  const { error } = validate(req.body); 
  if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

  let user = await User.findOne({ phone: req.body.phone });
  if (user) return res.status(400).send('Number already used')

  user = new User(_.pick(req.body, ['phone']));

  const activationUrl = 'https://www.thebeep.app/activate/' + user._id;
  const message = 'Welcome to The Beep! To activate your account and create your username click here: ' + activationUrl;
  const phone = '+1' + user.phone;

  const sms = await twilio(phone, message);

  try {
    user = await user.save();
    res.send(user);
  } catch (ex) {
    res.status(400).send('Invalid number ' + ex);
  }

});
```

What I want to be able to do is listen for success response from Twilio (insuring that the number is valid) before creating the user, and otherwise notify the user that they've entered an invalid number. But I can't figure out how to return anything other than undefined from Twilio promise to my route.

Thanks,

Evan

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `twilio` is that function in the first code block, simply return value of `client.messages.create()`. Since you're using `async`/`await` anyways, make the function async as well:

```
module.exports = async (recipient, message) => {
  try {
    const message = await client.messages.create({ ... })
    winston.info('Sent invite to ' + recipient + ' with SID ' + message.sid) 
    return message  
  } catch (e) {
    winston.error(e);

    // re-throw so that the route's try-catch can also capture it.
    throw e;
  } 
}
```

Then put your `twilio` call in the `try-catch`

```
try {
  // Should this line throw, user.save() will not be called.
  const sms = await twilio(phone, message);
  user = await user.save();
  res.send(user);
} catch (ex) {
  res.status(400).send('Invalid number ' + ex);
}
```

Comment: Hmmm...I just tried your suggestion and it looks like 'message' is being returned as undefined by twilio "Invalid number ReferenceError: message is not defined"